# Issue with cascading roles in symfony3 and sonata user bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I have my roles defined as follows:

```
security:
  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_PROFESSIONAL_SERVICES_MANAGER: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_BRANCH_ASSISTANT]
```

When I try to check for permissions in my controller as below:

```
if($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_PROFESSIONAL_SERVICES_MANAGER'))
```

The returns false because the in the profiler, the permissions appear to have been saved as shown below therefore:

```
"ROLE_PROFESSIONAL_SERVICES_MANAGER: ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_BRANCH_ASSISTANT"
```

Anyone know how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Roles are for users not the app.

With your code you are defining that a user with role `ROLE_PROFFESSIONAL_SERVICES_MANAGER` will have the roles `ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN` and  `ROLE_BRANCH_ASSISTANT`.

But now you need to assign that role to a user and sign that user in.

When you call `$securityContext->isGranted()` what it does is get the token from your current logged in user (wich you can see in the profiler) and check the roles of that user from the token.

So you need to have a user with the proper role assigned signed in.

If your already using SonatAUserBundle or FOSUserBundle use that command to create a user easily: `bin/console fos:user:create`

Then assign it the proper roles:

`app/console fos:user:promote nameOfYourUser ROLE_PROFFESSIONAL_SERVICES_MANAGER`

If your app has no user management system have a look here: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#user-management

Comment: The user already has permissions assigned through the Group which he belongs to therefore the code should work? I think I have similar set of code in earlier versions and these seem to work

Comment: Sonata User has no stable version for Symfony 3.Maybe that 's why it used to work and not anymore.Try downgrading to Symfony 2.8